# pointer doesnt move with two fingers on touchpad

Tags: touchpad

I recently installed ubuntu, and When I had windows 7, I could move tbh e pointer with 2 fingers on the touchpad, one finger ready to leaft click and one moving the pointer. In ububtu I can only move the pointer with 1 finger on the touchpad, but when I left click with one finger on the touchpad and then add another finger to move the pointer it works. Anybody know of a fix?

Comment: This is an indication your touchpad supports 2-finger gestures: the touchpad is detecting that you have a second finger down and is therefore not activating the normal movement action.  It may be trying to scroll instead... or maybe it's set to do nothing. You may be able to disable multitouch support in the mouse settings, but I don't know for sure so I'm just adding this as a comment.

Comment: To those that say it's unclear what he's asking: it sounds like he's using a touchpad where a "click" is done by pushing down anywhere on the pad.  He's keeping one finger still on the touchpad ready to click down while the other finger moves around.  Unusual yes, but each to their own, right?

Comment: I never take my fingers off the touchpad,and there are no multitouch settings. :( Would there be some kind of drivers that I would need?

Comment: Is there a 2-finger scroll setting like on [this page](http://i.imgur.com/tVGRr2X.png) and if so does altering that change it at all?

Comment: Nope it doesnt help

Comment: I'm outta ideas then sorry.

Comment: I have the same problem in Ubuntu 18.04. Did anyone find a solution? Thanks